# Problems with starting Uniform Server

Tags: apache-2.2

everyone. I am having a serious problem with accessing the Uniform Server that I had installed sometime ago to build a web database. The last time I had tried to start the server it, I was successful. I just tried to start the server again just a little while ago and the browser said the link appears to be broken. Can somebody help me fix this please? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of Uniform Server... I'm kind of doubting anyone else on serverfault has either.

You should check out the Uniform Server's [Support Forum](http://forum.uniformserver.com/) and/or [Wiki](http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/Main_Page)

Hopefully the software has some form of logging for debugging these kinds of things. Look for a logging option in the uniform config files, figure out where logs are stored.